# Possible to use extern variable in classes?

Tags: c++, c++11, extern

In C++, is it possible to mark a class member variable as extern?

Can I have

```
class Foo {
    public:
        extern string A;
};
```

where the string A is defined in another header file that I include?

Comment: It's not. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you're looking for static member variables?

Comment: I have a huge vector<string> that I'd like to include in the executable instead of having to read it in whenever I instantiate the object. I'll look into static member variables. Is there a way to define them in a different file?

Comment: Yes, in fact you're almost obliged to.

Comment: You could also make it be a static variable inside the .cpp file, that isn't a class member

Comment: The problem was that I was coding in the .cpp file, and the variable would've taken like 50,000 lines and I don't want that in the file I'm coding in (it's ugly and it slows down Sublime)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question and comment correctly, you're looking for [static data members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static)

Declare the field as `static`:

```
// with_static.hpp
struct with_static
{
    static vector<string> static_vector;
};
```

Define it in one TU (±`.cpp` file) only:

```
// with_static.cpp
vector<string> with_static::static_vector{"World"};
```

Then you can use it. Please note that you can use `class::field` and `object.field` notation and they all refer to the same object:

```
with_static::static_vector.push_back("World");

with_static foo, bar;
foo.static_vector[0] = "Hello";

cout << bar.static_vector[0] << ", " << with_static::static_vector[1] << endl;
```

The above should print `Hello, World`

[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iN7zrYSOQ6jAxUZU)

Comment: The vector is some 50,000 entries and I want to initialize it in the code (like have vector v = {"first_word", "second_word .... "fifty-thousandth word"}). Since it's so long, I want to be able to declare it in a different file. So I have Foo.h, and Foo.cpp; is there any a way to store the member variable in *another* file?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the solution. I want to be able to declare static_vector in the with_static.hpp file (like you did), but I *don't* want initialization to be in the with_static.cpp file. I want to have something like, static_vector  = {"hello", "world"} in *another* file. Is that possible

Comment: It can be any .cpp file in the project. (Or any header file, if that header is included exactly once, but please keep it in a .cpp file)

Comment: Is a vector strictly necessary? A `std::initializer_list` might have less overhead.

Comment: You might be right, but I'm answering to the best of my understanding of the question+comment

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try it out. How do I include the files in the headers? If I have with_static.h, with_static.cpp, and separate_file.cpp, how do I include each others headers? I obviously include with_static.h in with_static.cpp, but are you sure if I include with_static.h in separate_file.cpp, that I'll be able to do with_static::static_vector = {"hello", "world"} in separate_file.cpp? Sorry if this is confusing

Comment: Yes, as long as you compile them together later (your IDE + build system should take care of that automatically).